# Filtering pipe using sed

Tags: linux, sed, pipe

How do I

1. Send output of pipe to `STDOUT` 
   and simultaneously
2. Filter output of pipe and write it to a file

I tried

```
cat file | tee | sed 's/abc/def/g' >> log.txt
```

I get the desired filtered output in log.txt, but nothing is sent to `STDOUT` by `tee`

Comment: `cat file | tee everything.txt| sed 's/abc/def/g' >> filtered.txt`.  The filtered data should go to "filtered.txt"; the unfiltered data to "everything.txt".

Comment: `tee` did send everything to it's notion of stdout. It's just that you have `tee`s stdout connected to a pipe to be `sed`s stdin.

Answer (score 2):

If the goal is to see the complete file on the terminal while sending the filtered file to `log.txt`, then try:

```
cat file | tee /dev/tty | sed 's/abc/def/g' >> log.txt
```

In this case, `tee` sends output to stdout which, in this case, goes to `sed` and also to the file `/dev/tty` which is your terminal.

Or, if you have bash or another advanced shell:

```
cat file | tee >(sed 's/abc/def/g' >> log.txt)
```

Here, `tee` sends output to stdout and also to the file that is listed on the command line.  In the above, we ask bash to create a file-like object out of your `sed` command.  That is done using the incantation `>(...)`, also known as *process substitution*.  Whatever tee writes to that "file" will appear as stdin to sed which will process it and send it to `log.txt`.  In addition, `tee` will write to stdout which, in this case and unlike the first command above, is the terminal.

(I will assume that you are using `cat file` a stand-in for a more complex command rather than as a useless use of `cat`.)

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/abc/def/gw fileChanges' <fileIn >fileOut
```

This writes the changes only to `fileChanges` and the original file to `fileOut` (or to stdout if you do not provide a file).